# StackDriver is alerting even when policy is met

Tags: google-app-engine, monitoring, stackdriver

I have a Cron job setup on Google App Engine, that runs everyday at 11 am.

Given that the execution of the cron is crucial to my system, I decided to setup an alert for it if there's any failures, and this was setup as:

1. Create a metric with

   - Resource Type: GAE Application
   - Metric: Response Count
2. And filters:

   - Response Code >= 200
   - Response Code <= 299
   - Module ID: my-application
3. With an empty Group By and Aggregator set to NONE
4. Condition triggers if `any time series violates` condition `is absent` for `1 day`

So my intended behavior was "If this app doesn't respond 200 at the cron for 1 day (enough for it to be hit), alert me"

But I'm getting an email with the alert almost daily.

Is this a bug? Or is there another way to set this up? I'm receiving an alert, and when I see the cron page at App Engine, it was ran on the correct time, and returned 200 (success).

Comment: Your setup looks completely fine, it is exactly the same than  [this other post](https://medium.com/google-cloud/google-app-engine-cron-job-monitoring-bbf5c2ed6ca3). 

Are you still having the problem ?

Did you consider to create a Custom Metric based in logs https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/logs-based-metrics/counter-metrics ?

Comment: I did my config following exactly that post. I'm still having the problem, but it doesn't happen every day. The cron is always success